# How to write Filter Expression in Azure Data Flow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have filter in Data Flow of Azure Data Factory where I need to write expression for the following SQL logic(Where statement):

```
Where 
ID NOT IN (Select PID from Table1 where ptype_c in (100, 2000))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your source is SQL Database, you can just choose Query option.
[image]

If no, you can try like this.

1.create a Filter activity, get the data which ptype_c is in (100, 2000).
[image]

2.create a Select activity, change the column name.
[image]

3.new a branch of Source.
[image]

4.create a Exist activity.
[image]