# Azure Data Factory "Not In" Expression

Tags: azure-data-factory

Using Azure Data Factory data transformation expressions in mapping data flow;

What is the proper way to filter Dataflow join settings for Azure Data Factory when you want to express the sql statement "NOT IN"?

Example:

```sql
...
AND a.id NOT IN (2050, ..., 2057)
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your value of id is hardcode, you can create a Filter activity and use that expression `!in([2050,2051,2052, ..., 2057],id)` as Mark said. If so, please ignore my answer.

If your value is saved in your column of source, you can use Exists activity. Details you can refer to this answer [How to write Filter Expression in Azure Data Flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64886590/how-to-write-filter-expression-in-azure-data-flow/64887966#64887966).

Comment: Steve can you teach how to use NOT IN with array parameter ?
like I have input column called ID and array parameter is array_Id
can I write  ID !in(array_Id) in the expression?

Comment: @Aiden No, you can try this expression: ```!in(array_Id,ID)```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works for me. 
BTW, do you have any blog or video for Azure tutorial ?
I just start to use Azure from SSIS. I feel they are so different especially UI and each component functions. Please let me know if you have recommended sites for good practices. Thank you again !!

Answer (score 1):

`!in([2050,2051,2052, ..., 2057],a.id)`