# Azure DataFlow with Filter activity for input column's value NOT IN Array parameter (expression builder)

Tags: azure, parameter-passing, azure-data-factory

Is it possible that I can use expression and array parameter with Filter activity in the data flow to help me filter out no need records.

My source is a parquet file with a column called `FileID`, and I plan to give an array parameter which contains the list of no-need `FileID`, then in the Filter I can use expression to implement if `FileID` in the array parameter then pass it to the next step OR just filter out.

I tried these expressions but they don't work.

P.S. `ExistFileID` is the integer array parameter I passed into the data flow e.g. `[1,2,3]`

1. `FileID !in $ExistFileID`
2. `FileID in $ExistFileID == false()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer from another post. Thanks for @Steve Zhao sharing
[Azure Data Factory "Not In" Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65327677/azure-data-factory-not-in-expression/65336816?noredirect=1#comment122071209_65336816)

so if your filter want to implement that
When your **NewID** NOT IN **ExistID**, then pass the NewID.
Use following expression.
**!in(ExistID, NewID)**